# Displaying an interactive web map on my wordpress site

Tags: shortcode, javascript

I created an interactive web map using Javascript, and want to display it on my Wordpress site. I am currently displaying it on a browser **webpage**.

Things to note, the map uses data from a .csv file stored locally. This is my main issue as I'm unsure where/ how to store this data in order to display it on my website. The script also calls to openrouteservice API in order to generate isochrones.

Can I use the shortcodes feature to display the map?

Here is the HTML I used to create the webpage.

```
<body style="margin-left:100px;margin-right:100px" class="w3-rest"> 

<!-- A call to the function that initialises the maps when the page is loaded -->
           <body onload="initIsochronesMap();"></body>  
           
           <div class= "w3-cell w3-cell-middle">

            <h1 class="w3-text-orange" style= "text-align: left;">ABOUT THE ANALYSIS </h1>
            <p style="text-align: left;">
                Walking is a key mode of transport for foodbank clients accessing the service.
                Use the tool below, powered by <a href="https://openrouteservice.org/"> OpenRouteService</a>, 
                to investigate the proportion of users who live within range of the site.
                
            </p>

            </div>

        <!-- A division to hold the map -->
        <div class="w3-card-4, w3-rest w3-border w3-round-large w3-border-orange"
        style="margin-left:200px;margin-right:200px;">
    
        <div style="width:100%;height:400px;" id="map2" class="w3-container"> </div>

        </div>

            <!-- create a div to hold the input form and the button that submits it -->
            <div class="w3-display-container"

                style="height:75px;margin-left:400px;margin-right:400px;">

                <form id="timeform" class="w3-container w3-display-left">
                RANGE IN MINUTES <input id="time" type="number" size="20" name="time">
                </form>

                <button onclick ="isoParams()" class="w3-container w3-display-right"
                
                > GENERATE </button>
            </div>
</body>
```

Here is the code for my map.

```
let isochroneLayer, isoinfo, clientsTurf;

// Initialise the base map
function initIsochronesMap() {

// variable that holds the second map
map2 = L.map('map2');
    
// Centre the map on Manchester Central Foodbank
map2.setView(L.latLng(53.464774, -2.23179) ,12);

// this is a variable that holds a reference the tiles that will be used for the basemap
// I imported this map from leaflet provider
baseMap2 = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 18,  
attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map2);

// add a marker to the map at Manchester Central Foodbank
L.marker([53.464774, -2.23179]).bindPopup("Manchester Central Foodbank").addTo(map2);
}


// function to convert CSV coordinates to a turf points collection
d3.csv("./Coordinates.csv", function (Cdata) {

    // d3 parses CSV file, and creates Cdata as an array of objects
    // use .map to convert this into an array of arrays (turf constructor preffered format)     
    var dataArray = Cdata.map( Object.values );

    // pass the results to turf point constructor
    // define clientsTurf in the global scope, as it will also be used for the isochrone map
    clientsTurf = turf.points(dataArray);

    console.log(clientsTurf);

    });



// This function is triggered by the submission of the html form, and passes the inputs to the request function
function isoParams() {

// Get the time input from the html input form
timeInput = document.getElementById("time").value * 60;
 
// call to get geoJson data from ORS
walkIsochrone ("https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/isochrones/foot-walking", drawIsochrone);

// add the info box to the map
isochroneInfoBox();

}


function isochroneInfoBox(){

    // create a Leaflet control (generic term for anything you add to the map)
    isoinfo = L.control();

    // create the info box to update with the percentage of points falling within the isochrone range
    isoinfo.onAdd = function (map2) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'isoinfo');
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };

    // create a function called update() that updates the contents of the info box
    isoinfo.update = function (value) {
            
            this._div.innerHTML = value;
    
    };

    // add the info window to the map
    isoinfo.addTo(map2);
    
    } 


// make a request to OpenRouteService for a walking distance isochrone, based on the input range of the html form
const url = "https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/isochrones/foot-walking";

function walkIsochrone (url, drawIsochrone) {

let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 
  request.open('POST', url);
 
  request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json, application/geo+json, application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8');
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', '5b3ce3597851110001cf624863085b996464465cbf0974fe690fc4ef');
 
    //set an event listener for when the HTTP state changes
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {

        //a successful HTTP request returns a state of DONE and a status of 200
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {

            // pass the response to the callback function
            drawIsochrone(JSON.parse(request.responseText));  
      }
    };
  

    // set the input as a variable, in order to change it dynamically from the input form
    // then convert it to the required format for OpenRouteService before sending
    const changingInput = JSON.stringify({"locations":[[-2.23179,53.464774],[-2.23185,53.464780]],"range":[timeInput],"range_type":"time"}) + "'"

    request.send(changingInput);

    }; 

    // function that adds the isochrone to the map
    function drawIsochrone (data) {
        
        // count the number of points within the generated isochrone
            let pointsWithinIsochrone;
            for (let y = 0; y < data.features.length; y++) {
            
        pointsWithinIsochrone = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(clientsTurf, data.features[y]);
        
                }

      // create a variable that will be loaded in the info box
      pointsOutput = pointsWithinIsochrone.features.length / 1519 * 100
      percentageWithin = (Math.round(pointsOutput * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
  
      //update the info box
      isoinfo.update("<b>" + percentageWithin + "% OF FOODBANK USERS ARE WITHIN " + timeInput / 60  + " MINUTES RANGE </b>");
                
      // if there is a layer already added to the map then remove it
      if (isochroneLayer) {
         map2.removeLayer(isochroneLayer);
    
    };

        // load the isochrone into GeoJson and style
        isochroneLayer = L.geoJson(data, { 
              style: {
              weight: 4,
              opacity: 1,
              color: 'orange',
              }
        }).addTo(map2);   

        // zoom the map to fit the size of the isochrone     
        map2.fitBounds(isochroneLayer.getBounds());
      
}
```

Comment: Are you adding this as a plugin or as part of your theme?  Either way you would want to include the CSV file in there if it's not changing regularly, but if it, then maybe have it as an upload and then you re-assign it to the map via a settings panel.
For this, I wouldn't use a shortcode... ...I'd target a page using jQuery and have the map load that way.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to add this as a plugin, I have found a couple of plugins that allow me to input HTML CSS and JS scripts. Should I use one of these or is it better to create my own custom plugin? The .csv data is static so I want to include it, is it as simple as uploading the file to my page?

Comment: I would recommend building your own plugin.  Then make a template in your theme with a “container” for the map and use your JS to target the container and place the map in there.  You can then include the CSV in your plugin and simply reference it’s location with your script and then your function of parsing the CSV data, assuming it already works, will continue to do so.  So all your plugin becomes is a container that allows you to drop a JavaScript applet into a template.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try this!